# Can I put a one-line "banner" on top of Tmux?

Tags: terminal, tmux

Is there any way, using Tmux or anything else, to get a terminal that keeps a one-line string of text, a sort of banner, at the top?

In other words, I'm just looking for a way to set the first/top line of my terminal to a string but otherwise have an ordinary terminal.

Comment: Will moving the status bar to the top work?

Comment: More context would be helpful. What OS and Terminal emulator are you using? There are escape sequences that can be used to set the window or tab title in some emulators. Would that help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature in tmux as such but you can get what you want by using a combination of terminator and tmux.